# PHP best way to show a user's ping to the webserver?

Tags: php, shell, ping

I have several VPS' and want to use PHP or shell scripting to display the ping in ms from the client to the server(s) so the user may compare which server to connect to. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So, use ping shell command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want this to be asynchronous (so it doesn't stop the whole page from loading) then you could wrap something up in an Ajax call and then have a server-side script perform a ping on the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] (IP of the person visiting the site). As for performing the ping itself, you should just be able to wrap that up in a "system('ping ..." call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don’t think you can expect every common client computer to respond to a ping request … it is likely to be blocked by firewall/router etc. in a large number of cases.

Comment: @CBroe good point. I guess there probably isn't any fantastic way of doing this if we are talking about the server pinging the client via PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how sophisticated you want to get with your networking, you might want to give anycast a shot. The premise is that you give the same IP address to the two different VPS servers in the two different locations. When the client tries to connect to your server using a DNS lookup, it will find the single IP address, and depending on the closer server (ergo, better pinging server) should pickup that client. [Cloudflare does this, and they explain it in their blog.](http://blog.cloudflare.com/a-brief-anycast-primer) Although, this might be seen a using a cannon to kill a mosquito, but it seems to work and it might even work for you. Here's some data that shows that [Anycast is not evil](https://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog37/presentations/matt.levine.pdf).